# How do I change cursor on keypress (Ctrl) in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, onkeypress

Using jQuery, I would like to change the cursor on page when any key is pressed (for example Ctrl).
Simple task, however I can not get make it work...
This was my first idea, obviously - does not work:

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(){
  $(document).css('cursor','wait');
});
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think what you want is something like this:

```
$('body').css('cursor','wait');
```

You can't apply `CSS` to the `document`. Also if you wanted to only apply this css to the `CTRL` key press you could do:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
    }
});
```